# Lost order after Take/Skip in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a query in EF which takes information from various tables.

I would order on the basis of certain fields in this way:

```
query = query.OrderBy(x=>new {x.Cde_Conto,x.Data_1,x.Data_2});
```

If i do *query.TotraceQuery();* in sql server i get the desired result.

but I have to do an extra step..given that i have to show only a portion of data in the table inside my html page.

```
query.Skip(parameters.start).Take(parameters.length);
```

If i do this step i lost order in my query.
I do not know if the problem is *Take* or *Skip*.

Thanks.
Sorry for the bad English.

Comment: Are you sure the ordering is right without `Skip`/`Take`? Shouldn't it be `query.OrderBy(x=>x.Cde_Conto).ThenBy(x=>x.Data_1).ThenBy(x=>x.Data_2)`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight 
I am sure ... i checked several times.
I also tried with ThenBy() order but does not work.